# Null check vs Objects.requireNonNull in findFragmentByTag

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

As I had been placing null checks in Android `findFragmentByTag()`, the code inspection suggested me to add `Objects.requireNonNull()` method. When I applied this check, no more warning on code inspection. So which one is better?

I have gone through this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45632920/why-should-one-use-objects-requirenonnull). And as per my understanding (I might be wrong), **NullPointerException** will be thrown anyway.

```
           //3. Hide analytics fragment
            //if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_ANALYTICS_FRAGMENT) != null) {
                ft.hide(Objects.requireNonNull(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_ANALYTICS_FRAGMENT)));
            //}
            //4. Hide settings fragment
            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_SETTINGS_FRAGMENT) != null) {
                ft.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_SETTINGS_FRAGMENT));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `Objects.requireNonNull` [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-)

> This method is designed primarily for doing parameter validation in methods and constructors

That said, the benefits of using it are that your code gets freed up from some of the noise that explicit `if` null checks cause.