# Fix warning NullPointerException in android

Tags: android

Below code gives a warning when I run Inspect code. How can I change it to fix the warning?

```
File contents = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), "Contents");
            if (!contents.exists()) {
                contents.mkdirs();
            }
```

**Warning:**

> Method invocatiom 'getAbsolutePath' may produce 'NullPointerException'

and File `mkdirs()` is ignored

Answer (score 1):

You can use `boolean` to get the result of `mkdirs()`

```
boolean isMkDirsSuccess = contents.mkdirs();
Log.e("TAG","This is the value of isMkDirsSuccess " + isMkDirsSuccess );
```

for `NullPointerException` you can use

```
File contents = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(context.getExternalFilesDir(null)).getAbsolutePath(), "Contents");
//requireNonNull needs min API = 19
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Objects.requireNonNull only showing null location.Is it Right?

Comment: It is not require, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45632962/7948109)

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Shared storage may not always be available, since removable media can be ejected by the user. Media state can be checked using Environment#getExternalStorageState(File).

You need to do some checking first:

```
File externalDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
if(externalDir == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("No External files directory found.");
}

if(Environment.getExternalStorageState(externalDir).equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("External Storage not mounted correctly.");
}

File contents = new File(externalDir.getAbsolutePath(), "Contents");
if (!contents.exists()) {
   contents.mkdirs();
}
```

You can replace the exceptions with flags, or logs or whatever your programme needs.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageState()

Comment: @Diego If you found this helpful pls remember to upvote or mark it as answered https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers