# Java Scanner not initializing in one string() even though it does in another one

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, fileinputstream

The same type of scanner method is working in one place, but not in the other...
I am using eclipse as my code editor if that changes any answers. All variables have been declared elsewhere if not here.

If anyone knows how to fix this, you will have my undying gratitude :)

This one is working:

```
private String questionPicker(String str) 
{
    question = (int)(Math.random()*42);
    System.out.println(question);
    fileChoose = str.toUpperCase();
    String returnee;
    
    Scanner is = null;
    try 
    {
        is = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("triviaQ"+fileChoose+".txt"));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException z)
    {
        System.out.println("Error 004: File retrieve failed.");
    }
    skipLines(is, question);
    returnee = is.nextLine();
    is.close();
    return returnee;
}
```

This one is not working:

```
public String getAnswer() 
{
    String returnee;
    
    Scanner ls = null;
    try 
    {
        ls = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("triviaA"+fileChoose+".txt"));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException z)
    {
        System.out.println("Error 004: File retrieve failed.");
    }
    skipLines(ls, question);
    returnee = ls.nextLine();
    ls.close();
    return returnee;
}
```

error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Scanner.nextLine()" because "ls" is null
at jepp.JepQA.getAnswer(JepQA.java:60)
at jepp.JepGui.actionPerformed(JepGui.java:268)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6617)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6382)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2264)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4993)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2322)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4934)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4563)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4504)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2308)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Why do you catch the `FileNotFoundException` exception but continue your code like the file exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just catching exceptions is not enough; you must also change the code path accordingly.

Your code has the form:

```
Scanner ls = null;
try {
    ls = new Scanner(...);
} catch(FileNotFoundException z) {
    // print error message
}
// do something with ls
```

If the exception happens, execution continues after printing the error message and `ls` will still be null when the *do something with ls* code executes, which is why you got the `NullPointerException`.

To fix, either exit the method on exception:

```
Scanner ls = null;
try {
    ls = new Scanner(...);
} catch(FileNotFoundException z) {
    // print error message
    return;
}
// do something with ls
```

Or move the code that uses `ls` inside the `try`:

```
try {
    Scanner ls = new Scanner(...);
    // do something with ls
} catch(FileNotFoundException z) {
    // print error message
}
```

Note also with the last version, not only do we save a line of code (assignment and declaration as one line), but the scope of `ls` is limited to the `try` block; limiting scope is good coding practice.

Comment: We can learn from your answer: design-issue spotted, (anti-)pattern outlined - a brief recipe and focusing on essentials (try/with and exception-handling). Hope you don't mind that I applied your 2nd recipe to OPs code - as (over-)extended version ️

Answer (score 1):

Invest in debugging NullPointerExceptions (also known as NPE). You may consult the [link commented by Progman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919381/java-scanner-not-initializing-in-one-string-even-though-it-does-in-another-one/69919507#comment123596440_69919381).

#### Step 1: stack-trace analysis

Follow the Exception (here NPE) from top to bottom:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.**Scanner.nextLine()**" because **"ls" is null**
>
> at jepp.JepQA.**getAnswer(JepQA.java:60)**
>
> at jepp.JepGui.actionPerformed(JepGui.java:268)

What you can see from the top 3 lines in stack-trace:

1. your `Scanner` variable `ls` was null. That's why any method invocation on it like `ls.nextLine()` will fail with a NPE.
2. the failing invocation is in class `JepQA`, inside the `getAnswer` method, at line 60 of the file
3. the method `getAnswer` was called by an action-handler, method `actionPerformed` in your `JepGui`

#### Step 2: Why was an object `null` ?

In the method `getAnswer` you initialize `ls` as `null` - that's OK.
Then, inside the try-block, you open the Scanner on a FileInputStream connected to the file given by path:

```java
try {
    ls = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("triviaA"+fileChoose+".txt"));
} catch(FileNotFoundException z) {
    System.out.println("Error 004: File retrieve failed.");
}
```

This Scanner assignment, exactly the opening of the InputStream has failed, thus `ls` became `null` here again.

Reasons for that may be:

1. `String` argument passed to [`FileInputStream` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream(java.lang.String)) was `null`. Check or debug-print `"triviaA"+fileChoose+".txt"`. Also make sure that `fileChoose` itself is not `null`, otherwise the whole concatenated expression passed as argument will be `null` too.
2. there was an Exception like [`FileNotFoundException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html) when opening the stream or Sanner. But then, **why wasn't it catched and printed** as error?
3. So, there must be another issue! Back to (1): assume the `fileChoose` is `null` and as a result the concatenated *pathname* (file-name), too. Then read from the docs of constructors `FileInputStream(String) or FileInputStream(File)`, that it might internally create a [`File` from the *pathname* given as `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String)) and see the explanation there:

> **Throws:** `NullPointerException` - If the *pathname* argument is `null`

---

**Update:**
Thanks to [k314159's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919381/java-scanner-not-initializing-in-one-string-even-though-it-does-in-another-one/69919507#comment123599965_69919507) falsifying reasoning on my assumptions:

- Probable root-cause (2): error is printed on standard out (console), easily overseen when using a GUI.
- Impossible root-cause (3): can't be because if `fileChoose = null` then concatenated path argument would be `"triviaAnull.txt"`.

**Explanation:**

- (3) was tested in [null-concatenating demo](https://ideone.com/TeA2zQ). Hence, if invalid path argument passed, this causes a `FileNotFoundException` at line `ls = new FileInputStream(..)` so that observed `ls` NPE could never have been reached. Instead thrown exception must have been catched. Since no return handling was implemented the error prints to console (not shown on GUI) and flow continues with erroneous `ls = null` until observed NPE thrown at `ls.nextLine()`.
- So (2) must be the most-probable root-cause. However the `FileNotFoundException` could have been caused by `fileChoose = null` or any other invalid path passed to construct the Scanner instance.

---

#### Conclusion

Your file-name passed as argument *pathname* to `FileInputStream` constructor <del>was null</del> might have been invalid, either, because the **`fileChoose` variable was `null`** or else.

Compare the other **working method `questionPicker(String str)`** where you assign it as `fileChoose = str.toUpperCase();`. If you would pass a `str` as `null` here, then it may also throw a NPE.

#### How to avoid: Validate/test for null inputs

Add a *guard-statement* (see [Fail-fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) principle).
For example using `Objects.requireNonNull(fileChoose, "answer/question file must not be null");` where the second is the error-message printed when `fileChoose` is null.

See also:
[Why should one use Objects.requireNonNull()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45632920/why-should-one-use-objects-requirenonnull)

### Solution

As [Bohemian's answer correctly spotted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69919754/5730279) the design-issue:

- the sequence and dependency of your statements (`ls` related)
- unusual application of try/catch/finally pattern for I/O-Stream transactions

In case those were to roughly outlined, here a complete before/after example with explaining comments.

**Before:**

```java
String returnee; // consider a default return value to avoid any null at the end

Scanner ls = null; // a null Scanner is useless, consider initializing inside try (local scope is safer)!
try { // try block can encompass the whole attempt with every dependent statement
    ls = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("triviaA"+fileChoose+".txt")); // test filename at least for non-null, before try block!
} catch(FileNotFoundException z) { //
    System.out.println("Error 004: File retrieve failed."); // perfect to log
    // but how to handle: return or assign returnee with a default 
}

skipLines(ls, question); // depends on ls, so put inside try-block
returnee = ls.nextLine(); // depends on ls, so put inside try-block

ls.close(); // safe resources: close inside finally-block!

return returnee; // what if this is (still) null
```

Incorporating the second outlined pattern from Bohemian:

- everything inside try-catch-finally block

**After:**

```java
// default return
String returnee = ""; // default return value

// guard-statement with fail-fast
if (fileChoose == null) {
   return returnee; // returns the default or throw
}

String filename = "triviaA"+fileChoose+".txt"; // can not fail, because validated before. Worst case, e.g. least "triviaA.txt"

try { // block of ls dependent statements

   Scanner ls = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename)); // filename not-null
   skipLines(ls, question); // safer, because in local/try scope
   returnee = ls.nextLine(); // safer, but may throw NoSuchElementException

} catch(FileNotFoundException notFound) { //
    System.out.println("Error 004: File retrieve failed: " + notFound.getMessage()); // perfect to log
    // but how to handle: return or assign returnee with a default 
} catch(NoSuchElementException noElement)
    // log
    // and handle!
} finally {
    if (ls != null) ls.close(); // always close (if not null)
}

return returnee; // Avoid null, at least a default. Benefit: no NPE-risk for the caller.
```

See also: What [`Sanner.nextLine()` might throw](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--)

Comment: Your points 2 and 3 are flawed. I think the exception wasn't printed because the OP is using a GUI and the error is printed on the console _if there is one_. And your explanation for point 3 can't be right because the path given to `FileInputStream` is `"triviaA"+fileChoose+".txt"` and if `fileChoose` was null then the path passed to the constructor would be `"triviaAnull.txt"`.

Comment: @k314159. Now I incorporated your plausible reasoning as update to correct my flawed assumptions. We should always consider the human user and reflect over UI when dealing with inputs and handling errors.