# Validating a list: prefer explicit IllegalArgumentException over automatic ArrayIndexOutOfBounds?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, illegalargumentexception

I have a class that is supposed to wrap around strings found in some input file. The contract is that this files contains multiple entries (separated by # chars), to be precise: **at least** two entries should come out of that file.

Now I could do this:

```
public MyWrapper(List<String> fileEntries) {
   if (fileEntries.size() < 2) { 
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not enough entries ...
   }
```

or I could just do:

```
public MyWrapper(List<String> fileEntries) {
   this.firstEntry = fileEntries.get(0);
   this.secondEntry = someMethodThatMergesAllRemainingEntries(fileEntries);
```

That second piece would throw ArrayIndexOutOfBound at some point.

My question is: is there some *precedent* in the Java standard library that could be seen as guidance? (similar to the Java standard library call `requireNonNull()` that tells us to maybe prefer to throw a NPE instead of IllegalArgumentException for null arguments).

Note: I am **not** asking "what would be better", both sides have their pros and cons (I am slightly tempted to prefer option 1, as that is simply shorter).

Comment: I've seen "plenty" of fail-fast code in the JDK that looks just like the first version. I'd blindly say "the first one is the preferred/canonical way [citation needed]".

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793898/should-i-throw-a-nullpointerexception-explicitly-or-let-java-do-it-for-me

Comment: The first version helps to pin down the error at that location and explain it. The second version leads to searching backwards and maybe a "correction" at the wrong spot int the wrong way (adding an if or such). The fail-fast advantage. The JRE has not many cryptic errors like the second case. Regex and collections give carefull errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of precedents for #1.

For example, `ArrayList` performs its own explicit bounds checks and throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` with a descriptive messages (including both the offending index and the array size) instead of letting the underlying array access fail with its own exception (which in this example would happen to be a subclass of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, but that's beside the point).

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l1200

I personally would choose #1 over #2 in most circumstances, primarily because it allows me to be more explicit and provide a clear(er) exception message.